Blending of two functions such that the same prescription also holds for their derivatives
Prologue: It's easy to blend one real function $f(x)$ into another, say $g(x)$, by considering a convex combination with a transition function $\eta(x)$,
$$
h(x) = (1-\eta(x)) f(x) + \eta(x) g(x)
$$
where $\eta$ is a non-decreasing function over the interval $[a,b]$ with $\eta(x)=0$ for $x\leq a $ and $\eta(x)=1$ for $x\geq b $, see this answer for a cool example. In this way, $h=f$ for $x<a$ and $h=g$ for $x>b$. This strategy is nothing but the use of a weighted arithmetic mean of two values (the two values being $f(x)$ and $g(x)$), with a weight that depends on $x$.
Similarly, we may use the "multiplicative" version of this blending strategy (everything is positive):
$$
h(x) =  f(x)^{(1-\eta(x))}  g(x)^{\eta(x)}
$$
or, more generally, we may consider any sort of generalised mean or quasi-mean.
Question: let's assume strictly positive and smooth $g$ and $f$ and consider
$$
h(x) = M(g(x),f(x),\lambda(x))
$$
where $M$ is any kind of mean of two real numbers with weight $\lambda(x)$. The weight function $\lambda$ is such that on one side of the interval, we get $h=f$, and $h=g$ on the other. Is it possible to find $M$ and $\lambda$ such that the same averaging prescription is also valid for the first derivatives? Namely,
$$
h'(x) = M(g'(x),f'(x),\lambda(x))
$$

Is $(M,\lambda)$ allowed to depend on $f,g,a,b$?

@Karl yes, please feel free to assume whatever may help to find an interesting solution. I am mostly looking for ideas rather than addressing a well definite problem with exact hypothesis.

@Quillo since you're looking for ideas, could you provide a couple of example cases of the sorts of functions you are interested in?

@ChrisLewis, certainly. I am interested in strictly positive monotone increasing smooth functions $f$ (this is the "left" limit) and $g$ (the "right" limit) defined on $x>0$ with $0<a<b$. Therefore, $f'>0$ and $g'>0$ and are both smooth. There may be a point $a<x_0<b$, or even more points, where $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$. To guarantee positivity and monotonicity I was thinking about functions that can be written as $f(x) = \int^x_0 q(y) dy$ with positive $q$, so that $f'(x)=q(x)$.
